# FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow() not working with jquery .load

Tags: facebook, canvas

I'm having a problem with the canvas height in my app. I've got it set to FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow(); but when I'm loading a page into a div via ajax, it's not picking up the canvas height.

What happens is if the page I'm loading is quite long, then I load a page into the same div which is smaller, the canvas height stays the same as the larger page. It's not resizing the scrollbars to fit the smaller page.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Execuse me. But where is your FB.init(), it should be run before any FB function. Btw, try FB.Canvas.setAutoResize(); instead.

Comment: @eureka setAutoResize() will be depriciated in Jan 2012

Answer (score 2):

Also make sure you have a `FB.init();` before your `setAutoGrow();`

Answer (score 1):

i just had the same problem, FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow() did not work. in the end it was a weird problem, i had a javascript variable named "name". renamed it to "username" and now it works perfectly fine.
the rest did not show any error and my code worked without any problems, only the resizing did not work while i had "name". so maybe you should also just try to rename variables and/or functions...

Comment: This is a textbook case of why you should NEVER create global variables in JS. The only exception is a single namespace to communicate between objects (eg. window.APP)

Comment: I had the same issue. some script was doing:

function foo() { name = 'somename'
}

instead of 

function foo() { var name = 'somename'
}

Comment: I am having this issue.  I had some global variables but they don't seem to be the cause.  Is there anything else I should be looking for?

Comment: you need to make sure that your app id is correct, and that you call FB.init correctly before calling FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow(); also check the browser console for errors.